# Google Script - How to get email address from full contact name

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to get a email address from user full name. I have a list of more than 100 names and I don't want to enter it manually. I wanted to make a quick script on a google sheet that retrieve the email address of a list of names.

Any ideas? I can't find a function that get email address from a name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nvm I found the information:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contacts-app#getContactsByName(String)

I overlooked it

BTW, ContactApp class is extremely slow, so I recommend to fetch all contacts (around 2500 can takes up to a minute). See the documentation: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36754694

---

```
function contactsToCustomObj(lc){
   //Create custom obj
   var pl= {name:[],email:[]}, len = lc.length,i=0,h;
    while(i < len){
     h = lc[i].getEmails()[0];
     //Check if there is an email linked to this contact
     if(h)
       pl.email[i] = h.getAddress();
     else
       pl.email[i] = "*No email linked*";

     pl.name[i] = lc[0].getFullName();
     //Check if there is a name  
     //If not, in my case, all emails are first_name.last_name@hotmail.com
     if(!pl.name[i]){
       var t = pl.email[i].split("@")[0].split(".");
       pl.name[i] = t[0] + " " +t[1];
     }
     //RemoveSpecialCase is my custom regex class
     pl.name[i] = pl.name[i].trim().removeSpecialCase().toUpperCase();
     i++;
  }
  return pl;
}
```