# Google App Script - Lookup email address of @mentioned person in cell

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am working with Google sheets and we set up and record Teams in one of the tabs in the sheet.

We are currently asking teams to enter the team member name as well as their company assigned email address. Something Similar to Below:

[image]

I know that I can "@ mention" someone in a cell ("@Peter Pan") and it sort of links their contact info to that so that when you hover over it you can see their email address.

I was wondering if there then was a way to extract the email address from that "@ mention" via app script?

I know I can get the active session user with

```
Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
```

but thats not quite what I am after. I would want to lookup the Team Members email address by the name they "@ mentioned"

I have read up on the [ContactsApp class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contacts-app#getContactsByName(String)) but that seems to be deprecated and a lot of the examples on stack overflow make mention of this class too. [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859000/google-script-how-to-get-email-address-from-full-contact-name)

Is there a workaround to this that I have not yet stumbled across, or is this no longer supported?